# Unable to install prophet

Tags: python, pypi, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to install fbprophet and it is failing. I have pystan installed, I also tried using conda but that didn't work (let's focus on using pypi for this question). I also have vs tools installed. This is the error I'm getting. This is on python 3.9.

```
     command: 'c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\KE443FM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-42d3aqlm\\fbprophet_37617aca21054be8b94c7fb878637c28\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\KE443FM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-42d3aqlm\\fbprophet_37617aca21054be8b94c7fb878637c28\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\KE443FM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nm5haxot\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\fbprophet'
         cwd: C:\Users\KE443FM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-42d3aqlm\fbprophet_37617aca21054be8b94c7fb878637c28\
    Complete output (284 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\fbprophet
    creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
    INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9 NOW.
    WARNING:pystan:MSVC compiler is not supported
    stanfit4anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9_3479421244285704960.cpp

    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'Eigen::VectorXd' to 'const double'
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(414): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/functor/adj_jac_apply.hpp(333): note: see declaration of 'stan::math::adj_jac_vari<F,Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>>::build_return_varis_and_vars'
            with
            [
                F=stan::math::internal::softmax_op
            ]
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/softmax.hpp(78): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'void' to 'Eigen::Matrix<stan::math::var,-1,1,0,-1,1>'
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/rev/mat/fun/softmax.hpp(78): note: Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/mcmc/sample.hpp(33): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/services/util/read_dense_inv_metric.hpp(38): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/mcmc/windowed_adaptation.hpp(49): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/mcmc/windowed_adaptation.hpp(50): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/print_progress.hpp(52): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_fullrank.hpp(91): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_fullrank.hpp(105): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'const int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_fullrank.hpp(124): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'const int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_meanfield.hpp(48): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_meanfield.hpp(61): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'const int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/variational/families/normal_meanfield.hpp(76): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'const int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
            ]
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/io/cmd_line.hpp(32): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/lang/rethrow_located.hpp(117): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src\stan/model/indexing/rvalue_index_size.hpp(20): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    C:\Users\KE443FM\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_hwdirh1a\stanfit4anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9_3479421244285704960.cpp(5061): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\KE443FM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-42d3aqlm\\fbprophet_37617aca21054be8b94c7fb878637c28\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\KE443FM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-42d3aqlm\\fbprophet_37617aca21054be8b94c7fb878637c28\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\KE443FM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nm5haxot\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\ke443fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\fbprophet' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I did removed a lot of the code in the middle, but the error lines are there
domo

Comment: Check out their website. I think there is some special instruction to install and configure a compiler

Comment: Try using python 3.8 I failed to work prophet in python 3.9 but worked well in 3.8